# How to perform $lookup aggregation query deep into field in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to perform properly **$lookup** aggregation query **deep into field** in mongodb?

**templates**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("589888769ffec515d86f3e6c"),
    "tpl_name": "t1",
    "tpl_user": "some"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectID("589888769ffec123386f3222"),
    "tpl_name": "t2",
    "tpl_user": "some"
}
```

**subscriptions**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID("58c182ed320386f56a518efb"),
    "data": {
        "template": "589888769ffec515d86f3e6c",
        "email": "some.email@gmail.com"
    }
},
{
    "_id": ObjectID("58c182ed320386f56a518e7f"),
    "data": {
        "template": "589888769ffec515d86f3e6c",
        "email": "some.email@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Need to get list of templates with subscriptions in it.

I tried to get it like that.

```
db.collection('templates').aggregate([
    {$match: { 'tpl_user': tpl_user.id }},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "subscriptions",
            localField: "_id",
            // tried to use foreignField like that
            foreignField: "data.template",
            as: "subscriptions"
        }
    },
])
```

But no dice. Query returns empty subscriptions array.

Comment: You have to make sure both foreign and local field is object id type

Comment: Oh thank you! Please write this as answer, I mark it as solved.